# Spring Integration Mail Inbound Channel Adapter configured for POP3 access and using a poller configuration hangs after running for some time

Tags: spring-integration

```
<int:channel id="emailInputChannel"/>
<!-- Email Poller. Only one poller thread -->   
<task:executor id="emailPollingExecutor" pool-size="1" /> 
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3EmailAdapter" store-uri="pop3://${pop3.user}:${pop3.pwd}@${pop3.server.host}/Inbox" 
channel="emailInputChannel" should-delete-messages="true" auto-startup="true" java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
           <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-delay="${email.poller.delay}" task-executor="emailPollingExecutor"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
<!-- Java Mail POP3 properties -->
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
  <beans:prop key="mail.debug">true</beans:prop> 
  <beans:prop key="mail.pop3.port">${pop3.server.port}</beans:prop> 
</util:properties>
```

This application polls for emails containing application file attachments which contain the data to process. The email attachments are sent typically a few a day and are relatively sporadic. Since the files contain data for bulk load, we resorted to this configuration with a single poller for the Inbound POP3 mail adapter. Having multiple pollers caused duplicate poller invocations to pull the same email while another poller is processing it. With this configuration, however, the single poller hangs after some time with no indications of the problem in the logs. Please review what is wrong with this configuration. Also, is there is an alternative way to trigger the email adapter (e.g cron etc at a periodic interval)? I am using Spring Integration 2.1

Answer (score 1):

A hung poller is most likely caused by the the thread stuck in user code. I see you have mail.debug=true. If that shows no activity then a hung thread is probably the cause. Use us jstack to take a thread dump.

Yes, you can use a cron expression but that's unlikely to change things.

2.1 is extremely old but I still think a hung thread is the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to capture the thread dump when the issue manifests itself. Is there any other solution not involving use of the poller configuration to achieve the same functionality. This application is email driven and the frequency of emails is not very much. So, a cron job that kicks off periodically, say once every hour, may work. The only flip side to this is that the processing does not happen in a timely manner. If you can think of any other alternatives, please let me know.

Comment: In my experience, if the polling stops, it means either the thread is stuck in user code or some other code has exhausted the thread pool in the default scheduler. You should generally not run long-running tasks on poller threads; the scheduler only has 10 threads by default, but [can be reconfigured](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler). A thread dump will expose either condition.